# Weldjoint and force/torque sensor in DRAKE

Tags: python, drake

I am seeking guidance on how to incorporate a force/torque sensor within DRAKE. My objective is to install **a sensor inside a fixed cylinder** in DRAKE, enabling it to detect external forces and torques. Subsequently, I aim to simulate another object colliding with this cylinder. However, the current weldjoint readings solely reflect gravitational forces and do not include the external forces and torques.

Any insights or recommendations on how to achieve this in DRAKE would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

DRAKE's document https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__sensor__systems.html says adding a weldjoint can work as a force/torque sensor with the function get_reaction_forces_output_port(). I followed it and here is my code,

https://github.com/lllllyang/a-demo-for-drake/tree/main/weldjoint_sensor

As you see, it only returns gravitational forces.

Comment: What version of Drake are you using? There has been a significant amount of work on reaction forces that culminated recently with PR #19920.
Do you have a bare *py you could share?

Comment: @Alejandro Oh thanks for remind, I checked PR #19920, and it is a similar problem as mine. Now I updated to latest DRAKE, and it works.

Comment: Excellent! mark as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been solved by updating to lasted version of DRAKE.